# Adding a string to a gnuplot autotitle

Tags: string, key, gnuplot, title

I am using the gnuplot scrip command `set key autotitle columnhead` to make the lables for my data. The only issue is, the column head data is numeric and so it doesnt really mean much on its own.

Is there a way to add a fixed string to the autotitle, eg `"Year " + columnhead`, or alternatively, give my key a title?

Answer (score 2):

String concatenation using `.` operator with `columnhead()` works in gnuplot v4.6 ([documentation](http://www.gnuplotting.org/manpage-gnuplot-4-6/#dx1-25058)):

```
set terminal pngcairo enhanced truecolor size 480,320 fontscale 0.8
set output 'autotitle.png'
set key left Left

plot for [i=2:4] 'data.txt' u 1:i w l t 'f(x) = '.columnhead(i)
```

[image: gnuplot output]

Also, yes, you can set a title for the key instead, like this: `set key title 'f(x)'`.

Input file `data.txt` used in this example:

```
x 100x x^3 2^x
1 100 1 2
2 200 8 4
3 300 27 8
4 400 64 16
5 500 125 32
6 600 216 64
7 700 343 128
8 800 512 256
9 900 729 512
10 1000 1000 1024
```